# Have I got the 50 guys for you!

Tags: grammar

Based on the American sitcom Friends S04E10: [Transcription of "The One With the Girl From Poughkeepsie"](http://friends.tktv.net/Episodes4/summaries/10.html)

***Have I got the 50 guys for you!***

From the construction, I thought it should be a question. But it's an exclamatory sentence, actually. Why? Could any question be seen as an exclamatory sentence, only depending on the context?

Comment: I don't think the change can be made universally; only a subset of questions can be used as exclamations. For example, I'm having trouble with this one: _"Do you know the way to Portland!"_ (although, oddly, I have much less of a problem with, _"Do I know the way to Portland!"_).

Comment: It sounds like "Have I got the 50 guys for you[? Yeah, I've got]!" I don't know what "the 50 guys" refers to in this context, though.

Comment: @DamkerngT. *Rachel* wanted a guy to be her boyfriend, so *Chandler* went to his firm, found 50 guys who were willing to be *Rachel*'s boyfirend. So he told Rachel, "Have I got the 50 guys for you!" I guess he did mean he had found 50 guys, but I feel curious about it, because to me, this kind of construction is more of a question. But from his intonation, this is a exclamatory sentence, actually.

Comment: @J.R. I also found another one today. "Are you handsome."([SOURCE: Friends S04E21](http://friends.tktv.net/Episodes4/summaries/21.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentences can be seen as exclamatory sentences without depending on the context since they can be formed  by using the verb of the sentence in the interrogative-negative form at the beginning of the sentence. Examples:"Isn't she a charming child!" "Aren'tyou nice!" Of course, there are the exclamatory sentences that are formed with the question words,"what" and "how". Examples:"What a jerk!", "How clever he is!"

Comment: Thank you, Vic. But I feel your examples are a little different from mine. Your examples largely can be seen as *rhetorical question*, which begins with a "Isn't, Don't" etc. I could understand this construction perfectly. But my example begins with a "Have...", without either "not" or "What" etc.

Comment: @MarkZar: **1.** *HAVE* and *BE*, even when used as lexical verbs, are exempt from the *DO* support requirement. **2.** Your exclamation and those Vic provides are of the same sort: they are a special subset of "rhetorical questions" (questions which implicate their own answers), cast in question form, but spoken with exclamative intonation.

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you. I got it. Only this kind of "rhetorical questions" is a little weird to me. I've seldom seen it before.